# How to resolve "Error:Error: ' ' is not a valid resource name character" in Android?

Tags: android

> Error:Error: ' ' is not a valid resource name character
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.**
>
> C:\Users\Sushant\Desktop\AndroidScientificCalculator\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml: Error: ' ' is not a valid resource name character

How can I correct my errors?

[image]

Link for Project Files:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwjnJ7qmzQucZV82ODVLUmdVcTg

.rar file Link:

(https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwjnJ7qmzQucNDlBc3Y2T2pLV2c)

Comment: colors.xml shows color grid before every line?

Comment: It should be `calculator_background` not `calculator _background` . Remove space.

Comment: Yup its a space issue in `calculator _background`

Comment: when i removed space it says using twice calculator_background then i removed one then

Comment: errors are : Error:(550, 33) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/deleteicon').     2 } Error:(550, 33) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/deleteicon').  3} Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Comment: Few suggestions - 1. Use google, 2. use Git, 3. Make title more objective than subjective. 4. You can **post code here**, it will allow others to understand your problem better by looking at code.

Comment: Have you put deleteicon in `drawable` folder.?

Comment: can u please refer to above link ? i've shared project files in the question {sorry for bad english}

Comment: yes delete icon is there

Comment: two errors only                      C:\Users\Sushant\Desktop\AndroidScientificCalculatori\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml
    Error:Error: ' ' is not a valid resource name character

    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    > C:\Users\Sushant\Desktop\AndroidScientificCalculatori\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml: Error: ' ' is not a valid resource name character

Comment: have you remove space from color name? and Build again?

Comment: yes ive now errors in main question remain same

Comment: Pro-tips: please do not beg for help, and please add everything that people need to read into the question, rather than in a file locker. Do not ask for email replies, and please expect to do the work once you have been helped, rather than asking readers for free work.

Comment: sorry @halper but i was stuck on those errors for more than week or two and i'm beginner that's why, sorry for my immaturity

Comment: Regarding changes to your posts, please only roll back if the meaning of your post has been changed because the editor did not understand it. Note also that experienced editors should be given the benefit of the doubt - if you are not aware of how posts ought to be formatted in a Q&A site, then please leave changes as they are. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `color.xml` remove this line:

```
<color name="calculator _background">#2196F3</color>
```

In this button in your `activity_main.xml`:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/single_delete"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="1sp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:textColor="@color/calculator_color"
        android:background="@drawable/deleteicon"
        android:text="@string/single_delete" />.
```

you put `android:background="@drawable/deleteicon"` but instead of `drawable` folder you have `mipmap` folder. First you must include the `deleteicon` in yours `mipmap` folders and then you must put `android:background="@mipmap/deleteicon"`

**EDIT**

Done! Here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B09ZVpUGDlgpWFVxVzd3UUZSdkk/view

Comment: i re-named all mipmap to drawable in directory then rebuild got error Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

Comment: Done! Here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B09ZVpUGDlgpWFVxVzd3UUZSdkk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: awesome dude, thanks  i've an app without any errors and working app thanks you saved me i'm very grateful and thanks to all for helping love you stackoverflow.com :)

Comment: see the image can we do something to show remaining numbers ? drive.google.com/open?id=0BwjnJ7qmzQucMERoeEZHXzFJdTA

Answer (score 1):

After analysis your code.

There is no any `Drawable` folder in **res**.

You have to create `Drawable`folder under **res**.

And after you have to put **deleteicon**.png under **res>drawable** folder.

Its working fine. Please analyze your code again.

Comment: i did but those errors in main question remain same

Comment: have you remove space from color name? and Build again?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution: just remove white-spaces**

**In `color.xml`**

change this line  `<color name="calculator _background">#2196F3</color>` to `<color name="calculator_background">#2196F3</color>`